# How to have list of program on `dired-do-shell-command` with Emacs server started by systemd

Tags: dired, emacs-daemon, server

I'm using Emacs as a server started by the systemd user unit. 
And on any dired buffer when i try to do `dired-do-shell-command` or `dired-do-async-shell-command` I cannot autocomplete any program and need to write my command "by hand".
If I start Emacs not as a server I have the desired behavior and can autocomplete on the minibuffer.
To autocomplete I use `tab`.

I use the unit defined on the package and Emacs version 26.

For example, if I to autocomplete after typing `libr`, nothing appear.
Neither with `gre`. But both `libreoffice` and `grep` are reachable.

When I press `tab` nothing is inserted, and minibuffer shows `No matches`.

result of `getEnv "PATH"` on `emacs --server` (emacsclient) :

```
~/.opam/default/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
```

result of `getEnv "PATH" on emacs :

```
~/.opam/default/bin:~/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/default/bin:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl
```

Any idea how I could solve this issue ?

Comment: I'm assuming this is a PATH issue. Try evaluating `(getenv "PATH")` in both contexts. This question might be a duplicate of many `PATH` questions here.

Comment: Just to be sure, you might like to tell us how you requested completion (presumably by hitting TAB) and give us a specific program you tried and which obviously should be completed (e.g. `grep`).  Also worthwhile would be to specify what happens instead of completion: does TAB do nothing at al, or insert a TAB some whitespace, or ...?